# Image of boundary is boundary of image for continuous functions $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If we have a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, is it always true that $f[\partial S] \subseteq \partial(f[S])$?

I know that there are a few related questions posted, but they seem to all have additional properties (ie bijectivity) or are defined in other fields.

Edit: and just to be clear, I don’t have any additional properties of $S$. It may be open, closed, neither, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Define $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ by $f(x) = \sin x$.  Let $S= [0, 2 \pi]$.

Comment: Right, so $S’ = \partial S = \{0, 2\pi\}$ and $f(S’) = \{0\}$, but $\partial f(S) = \partial [-1,1] = \{-1, 1\}$. That makes sense, thank you. I didn’t think it was correct, but I couldn’t think of a counterexample.

Comment: @TuringTester69 Of course, acceptances of answers you find useful are always appreciated.

Comment: apologies, I thought I had accepted it. Thanks for the help!